# NodeJS business logic and current context data

Tags: node.js, express, request, datacontext

We are struggling now with NodeJS, as we don't want to pass some general request based data through lots of callbacks. We have multiple async calls, changed, updates in one remote method and we need to be able to extract the sessionId and customerId on every step without passing them as parameters to every function. Here is what we tried:

1. Writing to the "app" object is not secure and is overridden by multiple simultaneous request.
2. Writing to the "ctx.req" object doesn't change anything, as then you need to pass the "req" object to all callbacks.

Is there a good way to work with kind of request based context, that you can use everywhere in the application or you still need to pass some variable everywhere?

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is best for implementing stateless servers. I don't know your codebase and architecture. But I guess you need to use a persistence store like

> Redis or Memcached or Firebase(service)

with a token for each session. And use this token to grab the objects from persistence store. This is a pretty standard approach while implementing stateless servers. Firebase provides the added advantage of realtime updates and even completely bypassing the server if required.

You may have to show some code and design for a more improved answer.

Comment: But in this case, you need to pass the "sessionId" through all your callbacks ...

Answer (score -1):

You can use the javascript merit like Ex:

```
var topFunction={
firstFunction:function(){
console.log(id);
------//work you want to do
},
secondFunction:function(){
console.log(id);
---//work you want to do
}
}


function test(){
var arr=[2,3,4,5,6,7];
topFunction.id=10;
async.map(arr,topFunction.firstFunction.bind(topFunction),function(err,result){

})
```

> You got every time the same id in async call it is best way to use the the async call .You do't need to send the the id again and again .You can use this feature of javascript as context in request.The value of id different for every req